# SQL JOIN problem joining same table

Tags: sql, join, db2

Here is my mock up data:

Groups:

```
MAINGROUP SUBGROUP
1         A
2         A
3         A 
1         B
2         B
3         C
1         D
2         D
3         D
2         E
3         E
```

I'm trying to write a query that will return me one row per SUBGROUP, with one field for each MAINGROUP displaying the group number. If the subgroup does not have a matching group, I want that group field to be NULL.

Here's what I want:

```
Subgroup  G1  G2  G3
A         1   2   3
B         1   2 
C                 3
```

Here's my query:

```
SELECT 
    g.subgroup AS Subgroup, 
    1.maingroup AS G1, 
    2.maingroup AS G2, 
    3.maingroup AS G3, 
FROM Groups g
LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT maingroup, subgroup
        FROM Groups
        WHERE maingroup = 1
        ) 1
        ON g.subgroup=1.subgroup
        AND g.maingroup=1.maingroup
LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT maingroup, subgroup
        FROM Groups
        WHERE maingroup = 2
        ) 2
        ON g.subgroup=2.subgroup
        AND g.maingroup=2.maingroup
LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT maingroup, subgroup
        FROM Groups
        WHERE maingroup = 3
        ) 3
        ON g.subgroup=3.subgroup
        AND g.maingroup=3.maingroup
WHERE g.subgroup IN ('A','B','C')
```

And here's what I'm getting:

```
Subgroup  G1  G2  G3
A         1     
A             2 
A                 3
B         1     
B             2 
B
C           
C           
C                 3
```

Any help and advice much appreciated.

Comment: I'm a little rusty on SQL, but try adding `GROUP BY g.subgroup` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT g.subgroup AS Subgroup, 
    mg1.maingroup AS G1, 
    mg2.maingroup AS G2, 
    mg3.maingroup AS G3
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT subgroup FROM Groups) g
LEFT JOIN Groups mg1 ON mg1.maingroup = 1 AND mg1.subgroup = g.subgroup
LEFT JOIN Groups mg2 ON mg2.maingroup = 2 AND mg2.subgroup = g.subgroup
LEFT JOIN Groups mg3 ON mg3.maingroup = 3 AND mg3.subgroup = g.subgroup
WHERE g.subgroup IN ('A','B','C');
```

Comment: My first response was just attempting to adopt your query. This one should be better. Also, the first one had a bug or two :\

Comment: The first one worked fine, though. Is this one better for performance? Why would that be?

Comment: First, create the left-most table as just representing the unique list of subgroups. Then simply join in each additional table, linking to the subgroup of the left-most table, and the main group for the specific query. The assumption here is that `maingroup+subgroup` is unique.

Comment: The fewer subqueries the better. The first one had a bunch of subqueries, and they were linking to data unnecessarily. In answer to your last question as it applies to the first solution, however: I was accounting for the unnecessary linking by grouping the data based on subgroup, and getting the max value for each maingroup (when you're grouping, using max or min, the null values are ignored as long as there's a non-null value, so you could have used max or min).

Comment: Thanks Doug. This is quite difficult to think about abstractly. What would you suggest be the best way to understanding what is happening here? Would seeing execution plans help?